# Javascriptの連想配列で特定、複数の属性を削除したい

Tags: javascript

以下のような連想配列があり、title,textのkeyvalueを配列から削除したいと思うのですが、繰り返し処理などを使わずに処理する方法などありますでしょうか。

```
news:[{
      id:'',
      start_day:'',
      end_day:'',
      title:'',
      text:'',
      },
{
      id:'',
      start_day:'',
      end_day:'',
      title:'',
      text:'',
      },
{
      id:'',
      start_day:'',
      end_day:'',
      title:'',
      text:'',
      },]
```

こういう形にしたい

```
 　　　　{id:'',
        start_day:'',
        end_day:'',},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんな感じでいかがでしょうか。

```js
const obj = {
  news: [
    {
      id: "",
      start_day: "",
      end_day: "",
      title: "",
      text: "",
    },
    {
      id: "",
      start_day: "",
      end_day: "",
      title: "",
      text: "",
    },
    {
      id: "",
      start_day: "",
      end_day: "",
      title: "",
      text: "",
    },
  ],
};

obj.news = obj.news.map(({ title, text, ...omit }) => omit);

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: すごい。

`obj.news = obj.news.map(({ id, start_day, end_day }) => ({ id, start_day, end_day }));`

じゃないんだ！